# Can I say Dhammaniyama Anatta?

Tags: dhammas

Science can be called Dhammaniyama as per the following [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/49612/11541) to a question.

Can I say Dhammaniyama Anatta ? And what does it mean and why ?

Answer (score 2):

Dhammaniyama Anatta is correct, as in "the laws of nature are not self and are empty of a self."

Anatta Dhammaniyama is also correct, as in "all phenomena is not self and empty of a self, is a universal law of nature".

Answer (score 1):

Anatta is Dhammaniyama per [AN 3.136](https://suttacentral.net/an3.136/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=none&highlight=true&script=latin).

> Whether Realized Ones arise or not, **this law of nature persists**, this
> regularity of natural principles, this invariance of natural
> principles:
>
> Uppādā vā, bhikkhave, tathāgatānaṁ anuppādā vā tathāgatānaṁ ṭhitāva sā
> dhātu dhammaṭṭhitatā **dhammaniyāma**tā.
>
> **all things are not-self**.
>
> **Sabbe dhammā anattā**.
>
> A Realized One understands this and comprehends it,
>
> Taṁ tathāgato abhisambujjhati abhisameti.
>
> then he explains, teaches, asserts, establishes, clarifies, analyzes,
> and reveals it:
>
> Abhisambujjhitvā abhisametvā ācikkhati deseti paññāpeti paṭṭhapeti
> vivarati vibhajati uttānīkaroti:
>
> ‘All things are not-self.’”
>
> ‘sabbe dhammā anattā’”ti.

It means according to Nature (rather than according to subjective personal opinion) all things are not-self.

It means Thanissaro who said "not-self is a strategy" was wrong.

It means those who insist Buddhism is phenomenology rather than ontology are wrong.

It means those solipsists who believe nothing can exist outside of experience/mind are wrong.

It means those who believe the Buddha taught a middle-way between self & not-self are wrong.

It means most internet Buddhists have wrong view.

Comment: Could you provide an example of those who believe the Buddha taught a middle-way between self & not-self?